# Lambda expression in WHERE clause not working as expected

Tags: neo4jclient

I'm new to Neo4j and trying to do a simple Cypher query using a lambda expression in the where clause but for some reason I can't seem to figure out why this isn't working.

Looks like:

```
class HealthNode { 
    public string Name{get;set;}
    //Other Stuff
}
string Name = "Foobar";

var query = client
    .Cypher
    .Start(new { n = Neo4jClient.Cypher.All.Nodes })
    .Where((HealthNode n) => n.Name == Name)
    .Return<HealthNode>("n");
```

If I dump the Text and Parameters I'm getting:

```
START n=node(*)
WHERE (n.Name! = {p0})
RETURN n
//P0 Foobar
```

When I execute this, I of course get:

```
Cypher does not support != for inequality comparisons. Use <> instead
```

Why in the world is an extra Exclamation point to the name of the variable?

Answer (score 0):

The `!` means that the result will be false if the property doesn't exist. So, if you have more than one type in the graph, and that other type doesn't have a 'Name' property, neo4j won't bother matching.

See [Neo4J Documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/1.9/query-where.html#where-default-false-if-property-is-missing) for more info.

As to getting the != warning, are you changing the query at all when you paste it? Reformatting it? As I get the same warning if I do:

```
WHERE (n.Name != {p0})
```

but don't get any warning, and a successful completion if I use:

```
WHERE (n.Name! = {p0})
```

Comment: I used copy/paste to get the exact text.

Comment: Where are you pasting to? As long as there is a space between the `!` and the `=` you shouldn't get the error. If you run this query: `START n=node(0) WHERE n.Name! = "TEST" RETURN n;` in the cypher console does that show the same error?

Comment: I used copy/paste to get the exact text, and I also went to the shell itself and typed it in personally just in case there was a hidden character, but the parser returned the same error.
(sorry about the poor formatting, I don't have the hang of this site yet)
`START n=node(*) WHERE (n.Name! = "FOO") RETURN n;` returns the error on my local server (2.0.0-M04 Windows Community)
Oddly enough, the same exact query runs fine if I execute it against the live sample databases at [http://www.neo4j.org/learn/try]

I wonder if this is a bug in the parser in this particular version on the windows build?

Comment: Good catch, the online samples presumably run the stable version 1.9x not 2.0

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the cause of the problem here:

There was a change made to the 2.0 parser that implements NULL IF by default (instead of returning an error on a missing property) and removes the ! and ? operators since they no longer do anything.

[neo4j pull request 1014](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/pull/1014)
I suspect this will break a lot of things and not just Neo4J Client.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed in Neo4jClient 1.0.0.625 and above, when talking to Neo2j 2.0.